# Idiomatic way to convert char to int as an argument to isspace?

Tags: c, string, char

I'm using `isspace` in order to iterate a string and identify whitespace characters:

```
const char* s = "abcd efg";
const char* ptr = s;

for (; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
    printf("%c: %s\n", *ptr, isspace(*ptr) ? "yes" : "no");
```

As you know, `isspace` takes an `int`, not a `char`. The above seems to work - but I would like to validate whether or not it is portable, or "works by accident".

What would be the idomatic way to convert a `char` to an `int`, for use with `isspace`?

Comment: It's totally ok.

Comment: It is not ok, Eric is correct and Sombrero is wrong and Antti is out of votes.

Comment: And this question does deserve an upvote for good point - it is no accident that the type of the argument is *`int`*

Comment: I believe the safe way to refer to this character value is isspace((unsigned char)*ptr). This protects you in case char is defined as signed char. This way the automatic type promotion to int does not occur until after your character is safely representable as an unsigned char. The code case you show doesn't need to worry about the EOF value since you are not reading from a file.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `unsigned char` to manage characters. For example, `fgetc` returns a “character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`” (C 2018 7.21.7.1). Use `char` can result in negative values and undefined behavior, as explained below.

7.4 1 defines the behavior of the `<ctype.h>` functions only for arguments whose value is representable as an `unsigned char` or `EOF`:

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, if you have a `char` with a negative value, and you pass it to one of the `<ctype.h>` functions, that value is not representable as an `unsigned char`. And it is generally not `EOF` either. The negative `char` value will be implicitly converted to an `int` by the function call, but the value will remain negative. So the behavior would not be defined by the C standard.

Per 6.2.5 3, all members of the basic execution character set have non-negative values:

> If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

Per 5.2.1 3, The basic execution character set includes at least the Latin alphabet in uppercase and lowercase, the ten digits, space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, alert, backspace, carriage return, new line, and these characters:

```
!"#%&’()*+,-./: ;?[\]^_{|}~
```

So, if your string has any other character, it could have a negative value. Then, the behavior of the `<ctype.h>` functions is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: doubt no more. MSVCRT debug versions *assert* rather loudly on negative values.

Comment: I hammered the question. Also, EOF usually has value -1 and *it too* is accepted as an argument, and always returns "false" for any class, so it would be indistinguishable from `ŷ` say on Latin-1 with Turkish locale or so...

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for the answer. Was wondering, do you know the reason why `isspace` and family take an `int`? Why not an `unsigned char` than?

Comment: @AvivCohn: For convenience, they accept `EOF`, which is not a character. This is convenient for code that might want to branch on some expected classifications before it tests for the rarer `EOF` case, or the author just thinks their code is nicer that way. So the functions have to accept all `unsigned char` values plus one more. So an `int` is used.

Comment: @AvivCohn: I use EOF to detect the end of a file of binary data. Binary data can include the value 0x00 like any other value, so some other value (outside of 0x00-0xff) is needed to detect the end of a file. When used this way EOF does not represent a character - it is a way for the system to tell you that no more characters are available.